# How do you get the old and new values from md-selected-item-change (Angular Material) dynamic autocomplete?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, onchange, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's autocomplete, and I'd like to use the old value when the item changes.

The autocomplete directive is dynamically added to the web page, so using the $watch threads isn't really ideal for this case when there's potential for numerous amount of these autocompletes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **$watch** on the variable like this:

```
$scope.$watch('variable_name', function(newval, oldval) {
    console.log(newval) //contains new value
    console.log(oldval) //contains old value
})
```

So, whenever your item changes this watch block will be triggered and you can access the old and new values.

Comment: That would work with a fixed set of variables, but I have dynamic set. I can add a new autocomplete directive with a button, each having a different model variable. But if I were to have a watch on each of those variables, wouldn't that kill the RAM? I'm actually new at Angular, so I'm unsure how efficient it is with those threads.